# Can you host a Craft site on 1984 Hosting?

Tags: hosting

Does anyone have experience hosting a Craft site on 1984 Hosting? It's an Icelandic company whose ethos I like and I'm considering making my new site in Craft, so would be good to hear of anyone who's managed it.

https://www.1984.is/

Answer (score 3):

As long as a host meets Craft's minimum requirements listed here: https://craftcms.com/docs/requirements#server-requirements, then Craft should run fine.

Based on their shared hosting server specs here: https://www.1984.is/product/hosting/ (PHP 7, MySQL 5.5+), my guess is it'll run fine.

Comment: Thanks - I had a look at those pages before asking but couldn't figure out if all the relevant bits were there. The PHP plugins for example. I'm completely new to this so having an interesting / mildly infuriating time so far, but thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Craft 2 has fairly conservative requirements, so my guess is you'd be good, but easy enough to shoot them a quick email. :)

Comment: Have done, cheers buddy :)